# what is context->smarty->assign in prestashop and what is hook

Tags: smarty, prestashop

```
In indexController I have this

public function initContent()
    {
        //echo"asdsad";exit;
        parent::initContent();
        $this->context->smarty->assign('HOOK_HOME1', Hook::exec('displayHome'));
        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'index.tpl');
    }
```

But I don't understand. What is `$this->context->smarty->assign`, and what is `Hook`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assign` exposes variables that can be used in the smarty template. `Hook::exec('displayHome')` executes the hook named `displayHome`, and then the result is assigned to the variable named `HOOK_HOME1`.

Take a look at the [Smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.tpl#language.assigned.variables). There's also a list of prestashop hooks available [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5)

Comment: thanx @NilsH.I think i need to know smarty properly.